# Passing a global variable to a function - C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, global-variables

I am writing code for a router and I've made it to the part where I'm supposed to write code for a routing table. I've made a class which looks like this:

```
//Global variables
unsigned char Dst_IP[4];
unsigned char Nxt_Hop[4];
int Mask;
int OutIF;

RTEntry::RTEntry(unsigned char *dst_IP, int mask, int outIF, unsigned char *nxt_Hop)
{
    Dst_IP = dst_IP;
    Mask = mask;
    OutIF = outIF;
    Nxt_Hop = nxt_Hop;
}

bool match(unsigned char *IPaddress)
{
    bool isMatch = false;

    if(IPaddress == dst_IP)
    {
        isMatch = true;
    }

    return isMatch;
}
```

I'm getting an error when I try to compile due to the fact that dst_IP not is declared in the scope of the match function. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? It is probably something to do with pointers. I should probably mention that I'm quite new to C++..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only `dst_IP` I see "declared" is in the parameter list for `RTEntry`. Are you wanting to *change* what is passed into that (that is what it looks like you are doing).

Comment: Why would you pass a global which is *globally* accessible anywhere? Also, the name of the global is `Dst_IP`, not `dst_IP`. Also, why are you using globals?

Comment: `IPaddress == dst_IP` <-- that doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: RTEntry is going to be a routing table entry which I'm planning on making a vector of type. When creating an entry I want to declare the dst_ip, mask, interface and next_hop in the constructor. I've just changed it so that the variables in the top are private. The match function should check if the entry I'm "currently looking at" is the entry that I want for the packet in question.

Comment: @ZacHowland What does it do then?

Comment: Compare two pointers, not what they point to (the strings).

Comment: Also, `private unsigned char Dst_IP[4];` <-- that is not C++ syntax.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback. I should probably mention that I'm quite new to C++ and I'm coming from Java..

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that the `private` keyword you have in front of the globals is some non-standard extension your compiler provides. With standard C++, that keyword isn't allowed there.)

C++ is case sensitive. The global variable is named `Dst_IP` but in `match()` you wrote `dst_IP`.

Unrelated:

To compare C strings, use `std::strcmp()` or `std::strncmp()` (use the latter one if you want more safety with strings that might not be NULL terminated) from the `<cstring>` header. When using the `==` operator on pointers, it just compares the pointers, not the content that they point to. Or better yet, use `std::string` instead of raw C strings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. About the private identifiers in front of my globals, I have no real idea of where to put them instead. As of now they are written in the header file (.h), but I have no clue on where to write them in my program file (.cpp).. I should probably mention that I'm quite new to C++

Comment: @Zeliax Do not put global variables in header files. The text from header files is just copied into the source files when you include them, so with several `#include` statements, you get several copies of the variables. You should read a tutorial about how to use `extern` variables instead. Most of the time, avoid global variables altogether.

Comment: The code from above (the body of the thread) is from the .cpp file. I just don't know how to use the privates I've declared in the header file..

Comment: @Zeliax Why don't you start small, like with only one variable and one place where you use it, instead of trying to write a larger program.

Comment: You're certainly right. What I'm coding right now is just pretty important that I finish on time, so I don't really have time for aking baby steps.  Anyway I found a good guide after such a long time trying to figure out how to use the two different types of files. Thanks for your input though. [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/)